# Startup application entries cannot be added

Tags: boot, startup, autostart

I want a few apps like Synapse, Goldendict, etc to start up on boot, so I tried using the Startup manager and using the command of the apps found in usr/share/applications, then right clicking>properties. Reboot, none of the added apps were started, I checked the startup manager, and the entries I added weren't there anymore (only Dropbox, which was added when I installed Dropbox).

I tried running the startup manager using root in terminal, the startup manager was empty (no dropbox). I reboot, and none of the apps I added started (Dropbox did). I run the startup manager as root again, the entries I added earlier were there still.

It seems like running the startup manager as root or none root returned two "separate" startup managers since one had the one and only Dropbox, and the other was presented with all the apps I added myself.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you put as a command for start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a 12.10 on a netbook here, I fixed it with a dummy method:

First, run Nautilus as root

```
sudo nautilus
```

I located where the autostart entries are stored (it might be hidden so ctrl+H to unhide the folder). It is in:

**/home/USER_NAME/.config/autostart**

Of course replace "USER_NAME" with your own. It should be empty or with files with  **.desktop** extension.

Now find your apps for autostart located in

**/usr/share/applications**

Copy the apps you want into the previous autostart folder in your home folder. Reboot, and it worked!